# Generate md5 for Mave deploy

Tags: maven, maven-3, maven-deploy-plugin

Maven 3

I'm using the maven-deploy-plugin in my pom.xml file to deploy an XML file to Artifactory. Is there a way to generate a corresponding *.xml.md5 automatically with the deploy plugin? I know the install plugin has the createChecksum option, but I don't see it for the deploy plugin.

Comment: Better use the [build-helper-maven-plugin](http://www.mojohaus.org/build-helper-maven-plugin/usage.html) to attach a file instead of the deploy-plugin...

Comment: @khmarbaise, thanks!